# Update left join query help

Tags: mysql

I have no idea how to do what i'm trying to do.
Hopefully the data relationships are demonstrated in this example

```
UPDATE sym_entries_data_55'
SET value =  '46.00' 
WHERE (sym_entries_data_55.id = sym_entries_data_54.id)
AND (sym_entries_data_54.member_id = sym_entries_data_5.entry_id)
AND (sym_entries_data_5.username = 'namehere')
```

Answer

```
UPDATE sym_entries_data_55, sym_entries_data_54, sym_entries_data_5
    SET sym_entries_data_55.value = '52.00'
    WHERE sym_entries_data_55.id = sym_entries_data_54.id
        AND sym_entries_data_54.member_id = sym_entries_data_5.entry_id
        AND sym_entries_data_5.username = 'namehere'
```

Comment: What, in words, are you trying to do?  Are you looking for an explanation of the SQL?

Comment: update "value" in "sym_entries_data_55" where "sym_entries_data_55.id" = "sym_entries_data_54.id" = "sym_entries_data_5.entry_id" = "sym_entries_data_5.username" = "username"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE sym_entries_data_55, sym_entries_data_54, sym_entries_data_5
    SET sym_entries_data_55.value = '46.00'
    WHERE sym_entries_data_55.id = sym_entries_data_54.id
        AND sym_entries_data_54.member_id = sym_entries_data_5.entry_id
        AND sym_entries_data_5.username = 'namehere'
```

Comment: that error is because you put the word UPDATE in the middle of it

Comment: @Kirk Strobeck: I had a typo in my initial posting. Please use the code in my current answer.

Comment: @Kirk Strobeck: I'll be patient and wait. :-)

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli i appreciate the help! thnx

Comment: You really love taking screenshots :)